# Detect which result were chosen from MYSQL selection?

Tags: php, mysql, select, cookies

On my project i have a mysql query which select some results from my mysql table.So the problem is,for each result i display a button,when the user clicks on those button i need to store the result id in cookies,but every time i tried to make it work always the value stored on cookies is always from the first record!How can i make the value stored become the one from the chosen result?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Read the part about being specific and including information.

Answer (score -1):

Cookie can only store string. It can not store array. Use javascript join to convert it to ',' separated value before storing it using functions like -

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}
```